# Solve $3^{2x}-3^x\geq2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function

How to solve:

$$3^{2x}-3^x\geq2$$

I tried with $y=3^x$ and solved as equation: $y^2-y-2 \geq 0$

and I get:

$y<2$
$y>-1$

How should I proceed?

Comment: Did you mean $y^2 - y - 2 \geq 0$?

Comment: yes sorry, i have fixed

Comment: Now (for the first case) $y = 3^x \Rightarrow 3^x < 2 \Rightarrow log_3(x) < log_3(2)$, same for the other inequality (be careful there). Then take the intersection of all solutions sets.

Comment: @user8469759  The solution for the inequality $y^2 - y - 2 \geq 0$ should be $[2, \infty) \cup (-\infty, - 1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solutions you found are not correct. Correct solutions are $y\le -1$ and $y\ge 2$ but first solution gives no value of $x$ becuase $y$ is always positive. So now $3^x\ge 2$ gives $x\ge log_32$ which is the final answer.

Hope this helps !

Comment: different from WolframAlpha: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5E%7B2x%7D-3%5Ex+%3E%3D+2

Comment: @Taponiza Its the same. Uses base change rule!

Comment: The answer should be $x \geq \log_3 2$ since the inequality is weak.

Comment: @N.F. what are weak inequalities

Comment: A weak inequality is an inequality of the form $\geq$ or $\leq$.

Answer (score 1):

When you have $ -1 > y$  or $ y > 2$,

replace $y$ with $3^x$, it gives you (remembering that $e > 0$): $$e^{x\ln(3)}>2$$
Which yields to:
$$x > \dfrac{\ln(2)}{\ln(3)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $u=3^x$, then $u^2=3^{2x}$.  So in terms of $u$ we have $u^2-u\ge2$ or $u^2-u-2\ge0$.  You can factor the quadratic polynomial $u^2-u-2$ to get a solution for $u$, then take logarithms to get it in terms of $x$.